# Error in quicksort using Hoare partitioning with iterators, error with some specific small arrays

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator, quicksort

I am trying to make a C++ Quicksort algorithm using Hoare's partitioning. However I keep running into arrays that aren't sorted correctly, while most arrays sort OK. An example of such a troubling array is `{1, 3, 0, 4, 3}` which results in `{0, 3, 1, 3, 4}`.

The code contains the Quicksort code in the `quicksort` class, and fuzzy testing in the `main` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

class quicksort
{
public:
    template <class random_access_iterator>
    void operator()(random_access_iterator begin, random_access_iterator end)
    {
        quicksort_recursive_step(begin, end);
    }

private:
    template <class random_access_iterator>
    void quicksort_recursive_step(random_access_iterator begin, random_access_iterator end)
    {
        if ((end - begin) <= 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        auto left = begin;
        auto right = (end - 1);
        const auto pivot = *(left + ((right - left) / 2));

        while (left < right)
        {
            while (*left < pivot)
            {
                left++;
            }

            while (*right > pivot)
            {
                right--;
            }

            if (left < right)
            {
                std::iter_swap(left, right);
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }

        auto separator = (right + 1);
        quicksort_recursive_step(begin, separator);
        quicksort_recursive_step(separator, end);
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng{rd()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> size_dist{0, static_cast<int>(5)};
    quicksort sorter;

    std::vector<int> test = {0, 0, 4, 0, 1};
    sorter(test.begin(), test.end());

    bool has_error = false;

    while (!has_error)
    {
        std::vector<int> test_array(size_dist(rd));
        if (!test_array.empty())
        {
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> values_dist{0, static_cast<int>(test_array.size() - 1)};
            std::generate(test_array.begin(), test_array.end(), [&values_dist, &rd]() { return values_dist(rd); });
        }
        std::vector<int> original_test_array(test_array);

        std::cout << "Sorting array of size " << test_array.size() << " ... ";
        for (const auto& t : original_test_array)
        {
            std::cout << t << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        sorter(test_array.begin(), test_array.end());

        bool is_permutation = std::is_permutation(test_array.begin(), test_array.end(), original_test_array.begin());
        bool is_sorted = std::is_sorted(test_array.begin(), test_array.end());

        if (is_permutation && is_sorted)
        {
            std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            has_error = true;
            std::cout << "ERROR!" << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Array was: ";
            for (const auto& t : original_test_array)
            {
                std::cout << t << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Result is: ";
            for (const auto& t : test_array)
            {
                std::cout << t << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Possible output (error at the bottom):

```
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 2 ... 0, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 1, 2, 2, 0, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 4, 1, 3, 0, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 2, 2, 2, 4, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 1, 3, 3, 3, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 4 ... 1, 0, 1, 3,
OK
Sorting array of size 1 ... 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 1 ... 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 0, 2, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 4 ... 0, 2, 1, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 0, 1, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 4 ... 3, 1, 3, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 4 ... 3, 2, 3, 3,
OK
Sorting array of size 2 ... 0, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 4 ... 3, 3, 3, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 0, 2, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 0, 0, 2,
OK
Sorting array of size 1 ... 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 2, 3, 4, 1, 3,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 1, 1, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 1, 0, 2,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 1, 0, 2,
OK
Sorting array of size 1 ... 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 4 ... 0, 3, 3, 3,
OK
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 4, 1, 3, 1, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 2, 2, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 2 ... 1, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 2 ... 0, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 2 ... 0, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 2 ... 0, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 3, 0, 0, 3, 3,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 0, 1, 2,
OK
Sorting array of size 2 ... 1, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 0, 2, 1,
OK
Sorting array of size 3 ... 1, 1, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 4 ... 0, 3, 0, 2,
OK
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 2 ... 0, 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 1 ... 0,
OK
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 4, 0, 1, 1, 3,
OK
Sorting array of size 0 ...
OK
Sorting array of size 5 ... 1, 3, 0, 4, 3,
ERROR!
Array was: 1, 3, 0, 4, 3,
Result is: 0, 3, 1, 3, 4,
```

How can I solve this error? Everytime I try to solve it, I break something else. I also can't find good examples combining Hoare's partitioning and iterators as Lomuto's partitioning is mostly used in educational literature. I also want to avoid using std::partition etc.

Comment: If you have a small and known array that will always lead to wrong results, then it should be very easy to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement (while monitoring variables and their values) to see when and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Indeed, I have debugged this function for a while and know what goes wrong, but can't seem fo fix it correctly. My fixes caused stackoverflows, other types of arrays going wrong, etc. I can't seem to keep the loop invariants intact. I'm losing my overview over this and can't keep my head straight anymore thinking this through. I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes could give me the insight I need.

Comment: First try to break up more complex expressions into simpler ones, storing the results in temporary variables. For example, `const auto pivot = *(left + ((right - left) / 2))` could be simplified as `auto temp1 = right - left; auto temp2 = temp1 / 2; auto temp3 = left + temp2; const auto pivot = *temp3;` Also think about corner-cases like `left == right` or `right - left == 1` or `left - right == 2`. Or cases where `begin` or `end` are equal to the containers end iterator, or `end` is equal to the containers begin iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer to my own question. In my code, when the left and right iterators are exchanged and then cross each other, I end my while loop. Thus, it is `swap(lef,right)`, `left++`, `right--` and `stop`. However, the algorithm should do the `while(*left < pivot){left++;}` and `while (*right > pivot){right--;}` loops once more to set the separator at the right spot. This wasn't immediately obvious to me looking at CLRS's pseudocode, but there the while loops are also executed once more before the return.

```
HOARE-PARTITION(A, p, r)
    x = A[p]
    i = p - 1
    j = r + 1
    while TRUE
        repeat
            j = j - 1
        until A[j] <= x
        repeat
            i = i + 1
        until A[i] >= x
        if i < j
            exchange A[i] with A[j]
        else 
            return j
```

The correct code is thus:

```
template <class T>
class quicksort
{
public:
    template <class random_access_iterator>
    void operator()(random_access_iterator begin, random_access_iterator end)
    {
        quicksort_recursive_step(begin, end);
    }

private:
    template <class random_access_iterator>
    void quicksort_recursive_step(random_access_iterator begin, random_access_iterator end)
    {
        assert(begin <= end);

        if ((end - begin) <= 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        auto left = begin;
        auto right = (end - 1);
        auto middle = (left + ((right - left) / 2));
        const auto pivot = *middle;

        while (*left < pivot)
        {
            left++;
        }

        while (*right > pivot)
        {
            right--;
        }

        while (left < right)
        {
            std::iter_swap(left, right);

            left++;
            while (*left < pivot)
            {
                left++;
            }

            right--;
            while (*right > pivot)
            {
                right--;
            }
        }
        
        auto bound = (right + 1);
        quicksort_recursive_step(begin, bound);
        quicksort_recursive_step(bound, end);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical post-increment and post-decrement version of Hoare partition scheme similar to what is used in the question, has to compensate for the possibility that the right index may be decremented below the beginning of the array.

As an alternative, this example code uses a pre-increment and pre-decrement version of Hoare partition scheme, except that it skips decrementing then incrementing the left (b in the code below) iterator, using a goto to jump into the middle of the two partitioning loops. I could change the code to avoid goto, but an optimizing compiler is probably going to compile as if the goto was there as in my source code. For an even number of elements, it uses the left middle element for pivot (p = *(b+(e-b-1)/2)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

void QuickSort(std::vector<int>::iterator b, std::vector<int>::iterator e)
{
std::vector<int>::iterator i = b;
std::vector<int>::iterator j = e;
int p = *(b+(e-b-1)/2);
    if((e-b) < 2)
        return;
    if(*i >= p)
        goto loop0;
    while(1){
        while (*(++i) < p);
loop0:
        while (*(--j) > p);
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        std::swap(*i, *j);
    }
    j++;
    QuickSort(b, j);
    QuickSort(j, e);
}

int rnd32()                     /* random number */
{
static unsigned int r = 0u;
    r = r * 1103515245u + 12345u;
    return (int)r;
}

#define COUNT (1024)

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
size_t i;
    std::vector <int> a(COUNT);
    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        a[i] = rnd32();
    QuickSort(a.begin(), a.end());
    for(i = 1; i < COUNT; i++){
        if(a[i-1] > a[i])
            break;
    }
    if(i == COUNT)
        printf("passed\n");
    else
        printf("failed\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This gives an "Can't decrement vector itertator before begin" error. It also doesn't work on {3, 3, 1, 3} (result is: {3, 1, 3, 3}).

Comment: @MartenBE - I changed my answer to old but working code for iterator based quicksort.

Comment: Thanks, it give me some insight!